# What are the security risks if my server with github ssh access key is hacked?

Tags: ssh, git, github, ssh-host-key

I connect to my github repo using ssh keys which I have whitelisted in GitHub. I do pull/push to this repo from my linux server which is hosted in AWS.

If a hacker gains access to this AWS server, what all damage can he do to my code in github? Can he/she remove my repos permanently from GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that the SSH keys do not grant the user any GitHub-specific privileges; actions can only be taken in the scope of what `git` allows on the server, which shouldn't include account-related actions.

However, it may be possible for them to overwrite your commit history and force-push. I'm not sure if this would be permanent damage.

Personally I'd be more worried about unauthorized commits, e.g. backdoors added and such.